# Ensure all 3 lines throw exception before returning true

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, exception, try-catch

In order for my method to return true, I need to ensure that 3 specific lines all throw an error.

```
try
{
    // Wait until all three lines to throw exception
    Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock));
    return false;
}
catch 
{
    try
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock_bg));
        return false;
    } 
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock_img));
            return false;
        } 
        catch
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: i would add a variable and whenever an exception occurs , you increase by 1 . and at the end check if the variable = 3 then return true

Comment: Dont control program flow with exceptions

Comment: You should not use ```try``` and ```catch``` statements to control the flow of your program

Comment: @Hdot Have you considered [Polly's Fallback](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) policy to chain the three actions after each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exceptions to control program flow is generally considered bad practice. Instead, why not use the `FindElements` ([Selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/#locating-multiple-elements)) method which returns a list of elements and then check the length of the lists?

Something like this:

```
return (Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock)).Count == 0 &&
        Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock_bg)).Count == 0 &&
        Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(loadingTypesLock_img)).Count == 0);
```

The above will return `true` if the counts of the lists returned by all three methods are zero, so when no elements are found by any of them. If any of them find an element it'll return `false`.